# Expected 'this' to be used by class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

In my class, eslint is complaining "Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'getUrlParams'

Here is my class:

```
class PostSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getSearchResults();
  }

  getUrlParams(queryString) {
    const hashes = queryString.slice(queryString.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    const params = {};

    hashes.forEach((hash) => {
      const [key, val] = hash.split('=');
      params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val);
    });

    return params;
  }

  getSearchResults() {
    const { terms, category } = this.getUrlParams(this.props.location.search);
    this.props.dispatch(Actions.fetchPostsSearchResults(terms, category));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HorizontalLine />
        <div className="container">
          <Col md={9} xs={12}>
            <h1 className="aboutHeader">Test</h1>
          </Col>
          <Col md={3} xs={12}>
            <SideBar />
          </Col>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What is the best approach to solve this or refactor this component?

Comment: Where does the error point to?

Comment: That sounds like a linting error. If you don't want that error, you can always disable the linting rule. You are getting the error because `getUrlParams` could just be a helper function in the module scope though.

Comment: It is essentially an helper function, what's the best way to refactor and avoid this error?

Comment: Extract it to the outside of `PostSearch` class. You have to ask yourself question – „Should component be responsible for URL parsing?” If not – extract it outside according to **Single Response Principle** rule – one of the major rule that helps making decisions about OO.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

you should bind the function to `this` as the ESLint error says `"Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'getUrlParams'`

```
getUrlParams = (queryString) => { .... }
```

as you are not using `getUrlParams` during render (like `onClick()`) so the above technique is good which we can call it "usage of arrow function in class property".

there are other ways of binding too:

- binding in constructor  `this.getUrlParams=this.getUrlParams.bind(this)`
- arrow function in render e.g.`onClick={()=>this.getUrlParams()}` assumed that function does not have params.
- and `React.createClass` which with ES6 does not make sense :)

Comment: This only tricks `ESLint` into thinking you might use the `this` context. You still aren't using `this` for anything. The function should be made static or moved outside of the class.

Answer (score 30):

This is a ESlint rule, see [class-methods-use-this](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this).

You could extract the method `getUrlParams` and put it into a *helper*, or to make it `static`.

What could you also do is to move the `this.props.location.search` inside the method, therefore calling the `this.getUrlParams()` method without parameter, as it seems you are using it only once.

Therefore, this could look like:

```
getUrlParams() {
    const queryString = this.props.location.search;
    ...
    return params;
  }
```

A last option would be to disable this ESlint rule.

Comment: That got rid of the error, thanks for your help. Do you know why these errors occur, just for my reference?

Comment: I've updated my answer; it's a ESlint rule, see http://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this.

Comment: Do we have any permanent fix when you can not avoid parameters?

Comment: But, does anyone know what that point of that eslint rule is?  Why should we reference 'this' in a class method?  I looked at the eslint doc for this rule, and it never explains why it's bad to *not* use 'this' in a class method.

Comment: @mojave Despite the rule's name, its point is not that you should reference `this` from a class method, but that any method that doesn't use `this` should be converted to a static method, to make it clear that the method doesn't do anything instance-specific. There's also the sometimes-useful fact that a class's static methods can be used without making an instance of the class.

Answer (score 10):

```
getUrlParams = queryString => { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is to use this function outside of class and bind this function to class.

```
function getUrlParams(queryString) {
 const hashes = queryString.slice(queryString.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
 const params = {};
 hashes.forEach((hash) => {
  const [key, val] = hash.split('=');
  params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val);
 });
 return params;
}
class PostSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getSearchResults();
    this.getUrlParams = getUrlParams.bind(this); // add this
  }

  getSearchResults() {
   const { terms, category } = this.getUrlParams(this.props.location.search);
   this.props.dispatch(Actions.fetchPostsSearchResults(terms, category));
  }
  render() {
   return (  "bla bla"  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Another use case could be.**

Let's say you have method called ***handlePasswordKeyUp***. The body of function can be seen like this.

```
handlePasswordKeyUp() {
  console.log('yes')
}
```

Above code will trigger that error. So at least use **this** inside the body function

```
handlePasswordKeyUp(){
   this.setState({someState: someValue})
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The current [eslint documentation for this linter](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/class-methods-use-this) says:

> This rule is aimed to flag class methods that do not use `this`.

And:

> If a class method does not use this, it can *sometimes* be made into a static function.

So, applying their example to your code we'll have:

```
class PostSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getSearchResults();
  }

  static getUrlParams(queryString) {
    const hashes = queryString.slice(queryString.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    const params = {};

    hashes.forEach((hash) => {
      const [key, val] = hash.split('=');
      params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val);
    });

    return params;
  }

  getSearchResults() {
    const { terms, category } = PostSearch.getUrlParams(this.props.location.search);
    this.props.dispatch(Actions.fetchPostsSearchResults(terms, category));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HorizontalLine />
        <div className="container">
          <Col md={9} xs={12}>
            <h1 className="aboutHeader">Test</h1>
          </Col>
          <Col md={3} xs={12}>
            <SideBar />
          </Col>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice the `static` modifier to the function and the class name before invoking the function (instead of `this`).

Answer (score -1):

One, who is facing the same issue, can do this and fix it. Start the function with `/* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */` comment and close with `/* eslint-enable class-methods-use-this */`. Like this:-

```
    /* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
    getUrlParams(queryString) {
      // some codes here
    }
    /* eslint-enable class-methods-use-this */
```

Comment: This disables the rule, it does not solve it.

Answer (score -9):

A possible hack to this rule could be.

```
getMoviesByID(){
  //Add a reference to this in your function.
  this.funcName = 'getMoviesByID';
}
```

Comment: Having this as the accepted answer gives the wrong impression. Technically it answers the question, but in a really bad way by adding an unnecessary class var.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore exactly, it did not solved the question but just provided answer

Comment: Bad Solution. Just to get rid of lint error warning isn't the right solution. If the behavior is not desired, the rule of that specified lint should be handled in eslint configuration file.

Comment: Do not recommend this and a better way to handle this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/49061102/555362 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/51814498/555362