# Trying to create an axios http service using a generic http interface however linter says it expected 'this' to be used be a method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, axios, interface

As per the title, I'm trying to create an axios http service which implements an http interface. Here is the short example:

```
import axios from 'axios';

interface IHttpService {
  get<T>(url: string, config?: object): Promise<T>;
}

class AxiosHttpService implements IHttpService {
  async get<T>(url: string, config: object = {}): Promise<T> {
    const response = await axios.get(url, config);
    return response.data;
  }
}

export default AxiosHttpService;
```

However I get the following error by es-lint:

```
Expected 'this' to be used by class async method 'get'.
```

Is there something inherintly wrong with how I'm implementing this?

Comment: I guess that's because you don't use `this` inside this method. Have you considered making it static?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected 'this' to be used by class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249478/expected-this-to-be-used-by-class-method)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler the other one is kind of react specific

Comment: It's not, it's the same eslint rule triggered.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler but all of the answers talk about how to make this work with react

Comment: @Konrad thanks. looks like I need to add the static modifier.